Doctor Who episode where the Doctor and Clara split up and hide from an alien that can hear their thoughts
Please does anyone know the Doctor Who episode where the Doctor (not sure which one) and I think Clara are on a spaceship with another lady too.
They split up to try hide from the alien who can read/hear their thoughts. The Doctor tells Clara how difficult it is to not think of anything, to have no thoughts.
I think I remember the second lady has a vial of liquid or a pill that she takes moments before it is about to get her everyone thinks she is dead but she is not. The Doctor I think takes the same liquid or pill. Clara’s hiding from the alien trying not to think of anything to have, no thoughts.

Sometimes you gotta not blink, sometimes you gotta not think.

Could this be
Doctor Who Season 8, Episode 5: Time Heist?

When Clara is confronted by the Teller, the Doctor tells her the only way to survive is for her to clear her mind, so the alien can't detect her guilt.

The scene you're describing is quite vivid.

DOCTOR: Keep your mind clear, Clara. Keep your mind blank.





Definitely this one, the 'pill' in the question is a device they're told will vaporise and kill them rather than getting their brains melted down but is in fact a teleport
